# Delete Datatables row with media-id in button? $(this).closest("tr").remove(); won't work

Tags: datatables

I'm looking for a way to remove a row from a table, but I can't do this anymore. I used to do this by entering an id in the  tag, however nowadays I fill the table with json and Ajax and do not enter an id in the  tag anymore.

Now I do add an id in the last column of the buttons: data-id. Can I do something with this?

HTML:

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
  <td class="dtr-control"><img src="../images/red_thumb/1743.jpg" class="mediabank-preview-thumbnail"></td>
  <td>1743.jpg</td>
  <td>Beschrijving</td>
  <td>Redactie</td>
  <td class="sorting_1">01-12-2021 13:26:53</td>
  <td>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" data-id="1743">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
     </button>
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove" data-id="1743">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
     </button>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I try a lot with something like $(this).closest("tr").remove() But this won't work...

Jquery:

```
      $('#table_mediaBank').on('click', '.remove', function () {    // Verwijder media
        var id = $(this).data('id'); 
        var media = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();

        if(confirm("Weet je zeker dat je media '" + media + "' wilt verwijderen?")) {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'pages/delete.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {id: id},
          error: function() {
            alert('Er is iets fout gegaan met het verwijderen van media-ID ' + id);
          },
          success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            //$("#"+id).remove();   OLD WAY to remove the row when ID is in <tr>
            
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
          }
        });
        }
    });
```

The record is removed from the mySQL database. Why $(this).closest("tr").remove(); won't work?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The`$(this)` object which is giving you a problem is probably referring its enclosing jQuery Ajax function. You can check by logging it to the console: `console.log( this );`. Instead, you can capture the `<tr>` node before you enter the Ajax call, because at that point the `this` reference does refer to the table row. Something like `var row = $(this); var id = row.data('id');`. (Just a comment because I have not tested it.)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Apologies if you are already aware of this, but you can choose to accept an answer to your question, to let future visitors know that there is a good answer which works for you - and which may also work for them. [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). This is a completely optional step, but is recommended. (You can accept your own answer to your own question, also, as well as accepting other people's answers to your questions).

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
  $('#table_mediaBank').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    var media = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var row = $('#table_mediaBank').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr')); // In variable schrijven omdat het in de Ajax succes funtion niet mogelijk is om naar 'this' te verwijzen
    
        if(confirm("Weet je zeker dat je media '" + media + "' wilt verwijderen?")) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'pages/delete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: id},
            error: function() {
            alert('Er is iets fout gegaan met het verwijderen van media-ID ' + id);
          },
          success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            row.remove().draw();
          }
        });
        }
    });
```